# How do I return the HTTP Status Code from a method in my Web API to main?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, console-application, http-status-codes, system.web

I am working on a console app that can execute a few methods from an existing web API. I want the console app to write the status code that is returned, but I am struggling to find a syntax that works.

For example, here is an update method that is currently working as I want it to aside from the web response.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid order item number for the specific data you want to update:");
                    string oNum = Console.ReadLine();

    //more prompts for user to enter data to update

    ...

var update = _service.UpdateOrder(oNum, oProc, oProcDate, oComplete);
Console.WriteLine("Status code: {0}", (update.StatusCode));
```

I understand why my current status code response doesn't work. I have tried many other things, and I am just stuck as of now. What am I missing?

**Edit**

Here is the code that `_service.UpdateOrder` refers to:

```
public List<Stream> UpdateOrder(string orderID, bool processing, DateTime procDate, bool Complete)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(StreamUrl, Method.PUT)
        {
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
        };

        request.AddParameter("OrderID", orderID);
        ...


        var response = _client.Execute<List<Stream>>(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created || response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            return response.Data;
        else
            throw new Exception("Invalid input. Table could not be updated.");
```

Comment: What does `_service.UpdateOrder` actually return?

Comment: Should we assume that _service is a WebReference that wraps WebMethods in either an .aspx or .asmx file?  If so, the WebReference code generated by MS will attempt to handle any HTTP statuses for you, and will throw an exception for any of the failure statuses.

Comment: I have added the `UpdateOrder` code @JamieR

Comment: `_service` refers to my API test url. @BertCushman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are returning a `stream` from your `UpdateOrder` method.

Currently you can only access the `StatusCode` property inside your `UpdateOrder` method like you currently are:

```
if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
```

If you want to access the `StatusCode` property from your calling code then you need to return `IRestResponse` from the `UpdateOrder` like the following:

```
public IRestResponse UpdateOrder(string orderID, bool processing, DateTime procDate, bool Complete)
{
    var request = new RestRequest(StreamUrl, Method.PUT)
    {
        RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
    };

    request.AddParameter("OrderID", orderID);
    ...


    var response = _client.Execute<List<Stream>>(request);
    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created || response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        return response;
    else
        throw new Exception("Invalid input. Table could not be updated.");
}
```

and then in your calling code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid order item number for the specific data you want to update:");
                    string oNum = Console.ReadLine();

    //more prompts for user to enter data to update

    ...

var update = _service.UpdateOrder(oNum, oProc, oProcDate, oComplete);
Console.WriteLine("Status code: {0}", (update.StatusCode));
// You can access the List<Stream> from update.Data
```

Comment: That seemed to have gotten me closer, but even when I try to update a non-existent data set I still get "OK" returned as the status code.

Comment: @joey8oro That is something to do with the API endpoint you are calling. We cannot help you with that.

Comment: 3 years later this makes a lot more sense. Lol.

Comment: @joey8oro haha glad it still helps! I can't event remember writing this!